# Аффинные преобразования на плоскости с графикой

Tags: c++

суть проблемы: одна из нужных в проге аффинных преобразований это поворот, но я никак его сделать не могу, так как нужный угол 135 по часовой стрелке, и в радианах это около 2.3562, а это дробное значение, которое чертов int не воспринимает.
в программе *T[3][3]={{-1,0,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1}}* отвечает за поворот. Можете подсказать как повернуть на 135 градусов?

ВОТ МОЕ ЗАДАНИЕ К КУРСОВОЙ
Расположить фигуру так чтобы вершина В была в начале координат, а прямая ED была расположена в 1 и 2 четвертях симметрично оси ОY.
вот рисунок к дано.

[image: link text]

Или может я что-то не так сделал?
(не обращайте внимание на арабскую хрень после //)

[Ссылка на прогу](http://files.mail.ru/1CEDDC6CA3FD4273B55D94A3E0638EC2)

мои данные для ввода
    0 2 1,
    3 5 1,
    3 3 1,
    5 3 1,
    2 0 1,

Comment: А вы не думали выделять под угол вещественный тип?

Comment: @VladD убийственный аргумент)))))

Comment: http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=210
возможно эта статья поможет, сам ее использовал

Comment: @VladD, это было бы слишком просто. Но это же КУРСОВАЯ, а она не должна быть слишком простой!

Comment: @VladD я не понимаю как это сделать, про float я конечно знаю,но как именно к углу это использовать не понимаю.

Comment: teanЫЧ, может сможешь подсказать как это сделать в моем случае?

Comment: Чтобы было посложнее, предлагаю замутить массив значений синуса и косинуса для целых углов. Значения можно набить из справочника.

Comment: @Levons, во всех местах кроме int i,j,k; и int x, int y заменить int на float. Может сработать :)

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю: вы не знаете, как _поменять тип переменной_, содержащей угол в радианах, с `int` на `float`?